# Nuxt 3 build TS5023: Unknown compiler option '-'

Tags: typescript, nuxt3

Nuxt 3.8.0 with Nitro 2.7.2

after "npm run build" I got:

```
transforming (22) node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/plugins/chunk-reload.client.jserror TS5023: Unknown compiler option '-'.
```